# Existence of solutions of uniform elliptic equations with discontinuous boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

Suppose that $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is a smooth bounded domain, and $Lu=0$, here $L$ is a uniformly elliptic operator. For example,
$$Lu=\sum a_{ij} D_{ij} u$$
and there exists $\lambda>0$ such that
$$\lambda^{-1}\lvert \xi\rvert^2 \leq a_{ij}\xi_i\xi_j\leq \lambda\lvert \xi\rvert^2\qquad \forall \xi=(\xi_1,\cdots,\xi_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n.$$

Let $S\subset\partial \Omega$ be smooth (or good enough), then there exists a solution of $w$ such that
$$
\begin{cases}
 Lw=0&  \mathrm{in}~\Omega ,\\
 w=u&  \mathrm{on}~S,\quad w=0~\mathrm{on}~\partial\Omega \backslash S\\
\end{cases}.
$$

**Question** When reading papers about PDE, I often come across that the authors using the above results without citation, but I don't know how to prove it. At least, we may need to show the following admissible set is not empty:
$$
\mathcal{A} =\left\{ v\in H^1\left( \Omega \right) :v=u~on~S;~v=0~on~\partial \Omega \backslash S \right\} .
$$
Could you please tell me how to prove it, or any references would be very welcome.